# take a choice off if the name starts with A Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

thanks for your time:
i'd like to take one choice option off if the name of the People starts with letter 'a':

basically if People.nome or (Animal.pessoa) starts with letter 'A' i'd like to take the choice (2,'GATO') off. is there a way to do that or should i try another aproach besides a ChoiceField

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator



class People(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday_date = models.DateField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.nome)

def cant_have_cat(self):
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO'),
    ]
    self.maiusculo = self.pessoa.upper
    if self.maiusculo[0] == 'A':
        self.tipo != 2
    return field_choices

class Animal(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.IntegerField(choices=cant_have_cat)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.pessoa, self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO'),
    ]
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_choices)
    custo = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        prefix = 'animal'
        model = Animal
        fields = ('name', 'tipo', 'custo')

    def clean(self):
        people_name = self.People.nome
        upper = people_name.upper()
        if upper[0] == 'A':
            Animal.tipo != 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `__init__` of your `AnimalForm` to handle the logic. Something like this:

```
class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO'),
    ]
    field_choices_subset = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO'),
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if kwargs.get("instance") and kwargs.get("instance").pessoa.nome.startswith("a"):
            self.fields["tipo"].choices = field_choices_subset

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = forms.ChoiceField(choices=field_choices)
    custo = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        prefix = 'animal'
        model = Animal
        fields = ('name', 'tipo', 'custo')
```

Comment: it didn't work should i try to get People as a user? would it be easier?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that People is not a User. I edited the snippet, I did a mistake. Can you try it again?

Comment: still don't work, i'm gonna try this method with request.user now i guess it will be easier. because this way i gotta put the Animal.pessoa field in the same form as the Animal.tipo